# How to add character to end of value with Regex?

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regex rule (for Facebook's product feed import function).

I have a column called `ID` where I would like to take each ID and output the same ID but with a zero at the end.

So example values are:

```
515677
2642277
210098
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
5156770
26422770
2100980
```

So in short, add a zero to each value.

Comment: Two options: convert number to string and append "0" or multiply number by ten. I don't know why you want to use regex for this...

Comment: regex does not change values, it performs matching. If you need changes (based on regex), then you need a programming language. Which are you using?